# When would you use the html4f, html4s and html4t tags?

Tags: html, markup, doctype, html4

I know the **html4f**, **html4s** and **html4t** tags refer to different html 4 doctypes but I can't find reference as to when or why they would be used?

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide a link of the things you are saying? I have never heard of these things.

Comment: I don't think you should use them anyway.

Comment: @Siyah they are provided as snippets within Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks. Listed in the things to check out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are not HTML4 tags (elements), you can confirm this from the [Index of Elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/elements.html) in the *HTML 4.01 Specification*.

There is reference to them as "HTML Snippets" in the book *Introducing .NET 4.0: With Visual Studio 2010* by Alex Mackey. The book describes them as "doctype snippets" (shortcuts) for the following:

- html4f - HTML 4.01 Frameset doctype declaration
- html4s - HTML 4.01 Strict doctype declaration
- html4t - HTML 4.01 Transitional doctype declaration

So, on the assumption that you are using these "snippets" in this context, that is as a shortcut for document type declaration, then you can refer to the section [HTML version information](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#version-info) in the *HTML 4.01 Specification* for guidance on when to use them.

Answer (score 1):

Those elements do not appear in any version of HTML. They might appear in some language which you convert to HTML.

They appear to map on to the three HTML 4 Doctypes:

HTML 4 Frameset: For documents consisting of `<frame>` elements

HTML 4 Transitional: For use while transitioning from HTML 3.2

HTML 4 Strict: "Proper" HTML 4

These days, you are usually better off using HTML 5.

Comment: could you explain when or how they would be used in practice? I am asking purely as a matter of interest. Thank you.